# AmChart HeatMap with the same categories on value axis

Tags: charts, heatmap, amcharts

I have an matrix with correlation values beetween objects and I have to show it on heat map using amchart library. I'm using this [example](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/heat-map-chart/) (it's with jsfiddle) but I can't make it works to have the same values also on left axis.

Here is example what I have now, I need to have the same labels 'CAT[i]' on left axis.

How to solve it ?

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`labelFunction`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#labelFunction) to modify the labels of your value axis.

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ez1q3jx/) should fit your needs.